# Express Handlebars denied access to mongoose object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema, express-handlebars

Express Handlebars use to work in my app. With my current versions of packages, there seems to be an issue between handlebars and mongoose. One solution may be to put a .lean() on my mongoose methods. There must be a cleaner way. Any ideas of a resolution are appreciated?

Error:

```
Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "title" because it is not an "own property" of its parent.
You can add a runtime option to disable the check or this warning:
```

Currently installed packages:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.0.0",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.3.13",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution here:

> https://github.com/handlebars-lang/allow-prototype-access#usage-express-handlebars-and-mongoose

Install allow-prototype-access

```
npm install @handlebars/allow-prototype-access
```

Settings:

```
const Handlebars = require('handlebars')
const {allowInsecurePrototypeAccess} = require('@handlebars/allow-prototype-access')

app.engine('handlebars', expressHandlebars({
    handlebars: allowInsecurePrototypeAccess(Handlebars)
}));
```